# MS Graph: How to determine if the logged-in user has both Office365 and Azure subscription or not?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Question**: Using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Graph%20is%20a%20RESTful,to%20the%20Microsoft%20Graph%20API.), is there a way to query if a logged-in user has `both` the `Office365` and Azure subscription?

**Details**:

My `WPF-Core` app is using MS Graph to access Azure resources as well as Office365 services (Outlook schedule and OneDrive). My personal Azur Account does not have Office365 subscription. When I login with

1. an `Azure (admin) account` to my app the app can perform CRUD operations on Azure AD users.
2. Likewise, when I login as an `MSA account (Outlook, Hotmail, etc.)` the app can perform operations such as updating Outlook events, Upload/Download files to the logged-in user's OneDrive etc.

But in both case the converse is not true. For example, if I log-in using Azure AD account and try to have app update Outlook event (or upload a file to my OneDrive), I get the following error: `Tenant does not have a SPO license.`. So, if a user is logged-in with Azure AD account and try to click on the app's button that display or update user's outlook events I would like to display a message to the user that your Azure account does not have a SPO license. And, display a similar message in the reverse case (i.e. this Office account does not have Azure subscription etc.)

**NOTE**: The above scenario is not working for display purposes, as well. That is, an Azure AD login is not able to see Outlook events; and an MSA login is not able to see the Azure AD users list.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the answer is **NO**. We cannot determine if the user has Azure subscription.

MS Graph mainly manages the Azure AD resources while Azure subscription mainly manages Azure resources such as Azure App Service, VM, etc.

But we can determine if a user has O365 subscription (or the license under O365 subscription).

Firstly, you could use `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=userPrincipalName,assignedPlans` to get the logged-in user's O365 licenses.

We can find the **Sharepoint** license in the response:

[image]

In fact you may find more than one **Sharepoint** license in the response because the user may have multiple O365 subscriptions.

Besides, if the Azure subscription you mentioned actually refers to AAD subscription, then the method I described above is also suitable for querying AAD subscription.

The above content applies to AAD users.

If the logged-in user is an MSA, when you query `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=userPrincipalName,assignedPlans`, it won't return a property named `assignedPlans`.

Comment: What value of `assignedPlans` is supposed to return in your following query if I login as Azure AD admin in `Graph Explorer` and I don't have `O365` subscription? `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=userPrincipalName,assignedPlans`.

Comment: @nam If the user has no subscription, the response may be null. But if the user is assigned O365 subscription before and now the O365 subscription has been removed, the license will be listed but the status will be "Deleted." For example: `"capabilityStatus": "Deleted"`.

Comment: I just ran your query using my Azure AD admin login and got response with three attributes as follows (I've replaced some values with three dots for privacy reason): So, third value seems to indicate null (because I don't have O365). But it did not display `capabilityStatus` attribute even after I included it in the query. Do you know why it won't display this attribute? `{"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/......./$entity",
    "userPrincipalName": "myAzureADAdmin@someName.onmicrosoft.com",
    "assignedPlans": []}`

Comment: @nam `capabilityStatus` is under `assignedPlans`. If you don't have O365 subscription, you can ignore this property.

Comment: The subscription I referred is for `AAD subscription`. I'm still not clear on: For now I get `"assignedPlans": []` because I do not have `O365` . If I did have `O365`  what would be the value of `assignedPlans`?

Comment: @nam It will show like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcRUN.png. Please note it lists all the licenses under O365 subscription you have. Not the O365 subscription. If you want to know the licenses are from which O365 subscription, you need to query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscribedSkus` to compare the results. And after you get the Service plans name, you can find the Product name here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference.

Comment: @nam AAD basic subscription will not show in the response. If you have AAD Premium license, it will be listed. See the same screenshot (the first one): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcRUN.png.

Comment: @nam Do you have any further concerns?

Comment: I have put the project on hold for now. Will come back to it after holidays.